# Calculating Cumulative Commission Amounts

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a commission banding table containing the following:

```
Lower    Upper     Percentage
0        300       45
300.01   800       50
800.01   1500      55
```

The lower and upper amounts are currency values, and i need to calculate a cumulative amount to pay based on the total sales, using the percentage amount relevant to the total sales.

If i then have a total sales amount of 350, my commission should be calculated as the following:

first 300 of the total would be using the 45%
the remaining 50 would be using the 50%
so my total would be 
   `300*45% = 135`
   `50*50% = 25`
   `Total = 160`

I am updating a table with the amounts via a sproc so would need to accommodate this in there.

How is the best way to go about this?

Note : the sproc below has the correct column names, where as the example above i changed the names of the columns for simplicity.  The SPROC also joins the table where the bands are stored, and the update table is a kind of working/reporting table

EDIT : sproc update section:

```
UPDATE CommissionCalculationDetails
SET TotalCommissionAmount = 
case
  when TotalSales > Upper then Upper
  when TotalSale > Lower then @sales - Lower
  else 0
end 
* Percentage / 100
FROM CommissionCalculationDetails
LEFT JOIN CommissionBand 
ON TotalSales > CommissionBand.Lower
AND TotalSales < CommisionBand.Upper
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I propose that you store  non-inclusive lower bounds instead (ex: `300` instead of `300.01`) and use strictly greater than when comparing against it. As it stands, the value `300.005` would not be correctly categorized.

If this was the case, you could compute the total commission using the following query:

```
select
  sum (
    case
      when @sales > Upper then Upper
      when @sales > Lower then @sales - Lower
      else 0
    end 
    * Percentage / 100
  ) as TotalCommission
from CommissionTable
```

Here's an online test version of this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/87f12/8

---

Slightly offtopic: Your table currently contains redundant information; each lower bound is (more or less) equal to the previous upper bound. Although this is not essential, you could think of a way to store, for example, upper bounds only (and have a `null` signifying *unbounded*).

---

For the update, one possible solution is to extract the commission calculation in a [function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx), like so:

```
create function ufn_CalculateCommission(@Sales money) 
  returns money 
as
begin

  declare @result money

  select 
    @result = 
      sum (
        case
          when @sales > Upper then Upper
          when @sales > Lower then @sales - Lower
          else 0
        end 
        * Percentage / 100
      )
  from CommissionBand

  return @result
end
```

After declaring the function, the update can be simplified to:

```
update CommissionCalculationDetails
set TotalCommissionAmount = dbo.ufn_CalculateCommission(TotalSales);
```

Here's how it works: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f4405/4

Comment: Thanks! I can change the bounds so this should work....only other thing is that the SPROC being using will need to have the TotalCommission (in your example) as an update, so would the aggregate fail in this case?

Comment: @Stuart1044 can you please update your question with the relevant stored proc code?

Comment: @Stuart1044 please see the update to my answer. I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you sooooo much, this was confusing me, but in the end the solution is simply, just a case of stepping back and having a second pair of eyes.